# Multilingual model error messages aren't translated

Tags: python, django, multilingual

I'm using Multilingual Models.

The problem is that the errors messages doesn't get translated in the template.

this is the multilingual forms.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet
from django import forms

from . import settings


class TranslationFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
"""
FormSet for TranslationInlines, making sure that at least one translation
is required and that sensible default values are selected for the language
choice.
"""

def clean(self):
    """
    Make sure there is at least a translation has been filled in. If a
    default language has been specified, make sure that it exists amongst
    translations.
    """

    # First make sure the super's clean method is called upon.
    super(TranslationFormSet, self).clean()

    if settings.HIDE_LANGUAGE:
        return

    if len(self.forms) < 2 and not any(self.errors):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            _('All translations should be provided.')
        )
         ....................
```

for example : `_('All translations should be provided.')` message doesn't get translated in the template.

I don't know what's wrong, since the use of `_(..)` is there.

PS: I installed the multilingual model using `pip`

Now,it figures under ExternalLibraries/site-packages

Any help?

Comment: Did you make `manage.py makemessages` and `manage.py compilemessages`?

Comment: do you mean `django-admin makemessages`? yess, but I didn't find the 'All translations should be provided.' in the .po file after running it

Comment: You need to input translations to the po file manually. From the docs: msgstr is where you put the language-specific translation. It starts out empty, so it’s your responsibility to change it. Make sure you keep the quotes around your translation.

Comment: I know that, :3 The problem is that after running `django-admin makemessages`, I don't find the  `msgid "All translations should be translated" msgstr "" ` block to complete it